# SharePoint 2013 user profile service change homepage

Tags: sharepoint

I have a sharepoint 2013 farm that start and configure and sync user profile service on it successfully. now when each user browse site homepage first time, it shows a white page with 2 link that is go to site and change attribute, how could I disable this page?

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error when one of a user profile properties wasn't set. In my case the user's location wasn't set. If the user goes to edit user their profile and save it without any changes, it fixes the issue. In my case, only few users were affected by this issue. You can write script to update missing property for all the users.